# Kong dbless/kong-oidc - Is it possible to use kong-oidc plugin dbless?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I have not been able to find any documentation using the nokia/kong-oidc plugin in dbless mode. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into this problem, I used two git repos to come up with the solution. You can find them [here](https://github.com/d4rkstar/kong-konga-keycloak) and [here](https://github.com/MossabTN/quarkus-microservices-poc/tree/master/kubernetes/gateway).